# Opportunity close date is not being set to today when closed while close date is in the future

Tags: apex, unit-test, opportunity

We are implementing an override of the close date functionality. By default, [opportunities that are closed and have a close date set to the future get their close date set to today.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323585&language=en_US&type=1) We want this to hold true for all opportunities except for opportunities of a specific record type. So I wrote a trigger to persist the original close date for these opportunities.

However I am struggling to get this functionality to work in a test. My first assertion throws an error that the close date is not being changed.

> Assertion Failed: Expected: 2019-07-01 00:00:00, Actual: 2019-07-06 00:00:00

I have verified that when I first close the opportunity the `not persisting` debug is printed. I've also verified there are no other triggers/workflows affecting this process.

Why is the close date not changing as it should?

Trigger:

```
public static void persistOriginalCloseDate(Map<Id, Opportunity> opps, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldOpps) {
    Id maintenanceRecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' AND DeveloperName = 'Maintenance_Renewal'].Id;
    for (Opportunity opp : opps.values()) {
        Opportunity oldOpp = oldOpps.get(opp.Id);
        if (opp.RecordTypeId == maintenanceRecordTypeId && opp.IsWon == true && oldOpp.IsWon == false && opp.CloseDate != oldOpp.CloseDate) {
            opp.CloseDate = oldOpp.CloseDate;
            System.debug('persisting');
        } else {
            System.debug('not persisting');
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@IsTest
static void persistOriginalCloseDateTest() {
    Account a = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :ACCOUNT_NAME];

    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
    opp.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
    opp.CloseDate = Date.today().addDays(5);
    opp.StageName = 'Active';
    opp.AccountId = a.Id;
    insert opp;

    Test.startTest();
        opp.StageName = 'Won';
        update opp;

        opp = [SELECT Id, CloseDate, StageName, RecordTypeId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opp.Id];
        System.assertEquals(Date.today(), opp.CloseDate);

        opp.RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' AND DeveloperName = 'Maintenance_Renewal'].Id;
        opp.StageName = 'Active';
        opp.CloseDate = Date.today().addDays(1);
        update opp;

        opp.StageName = 'Won';
        update opp;

        opp = [SELECT Id, CloseDate FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opp.Id];
        System.assertEquals(Date.today().addDays(1), opp.CloseDate);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: does SFDC coerce the close date `before` the field is presented to the trigger or after the transaction commit?

Comment: @cropredy it happens after the transaction. I am looking at the debug log and it happens in `OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/OpportunityTrigger`, which is called after my before trigger

Comment: if it is coerced when you execute the after update; then the transaction has not yet finished; you can either update (via DML - watch for recursion) in after update or defer to a queueable/future to 'uncoerce' (watch for wfrs/process builders that will execute before the async

Comment: ahhhh this makes sense. I could also do a `System.runAs` in the test to get a new transaction. Thank you.

Comment: @cropredy Can you elaborate more on your solution? Calling `System.runAs` does not work in my test. I should state, my current trigger works as intended. I am only asking for how to get the CloseDate that salesforce's trigger sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't explicity say so in your post, but since your trigger method isn't doing any DML, I'm assuming that you're calling the method from a `before update` trigger. And this is the problem. Although it's not documented where in the [Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) a system field update like this takes place, a quick test shows that it hasn't happened in the `before update` context:

```
trigger CloseDateTest on Opportunity (before update, after update) {
    if (Trigger.isBefore) {
        for(Opportunity o : Trigger.New) {
            System.debug('Old Close Date: ' + Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).CloseDate);
            System.debug('New Close Date Before: ' + o.CloseDate);
            System.debug('Changed Before? ' + !(Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).CloseDate == o.CloseDate));
        }
    }

    if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        for(Opportunity o : Trigger.New) {
            System.debug('New Close Date After: ' + o.CloseDate);
            System.debug('Changed After? ' + !(Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).CloseDate == o.CloseDate));
        }
    }
}
```

Which generates this debug output for an Opp with a CloseDate of 2019-09-30 that is updated to Closed/Won:

```
14:05:50:038 USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|Old Close Date: 2019-09-30 00:00:00
14:05:50:038 USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|New Close Date Before: 2019-09-30 00:00:00
14:05:50:038 USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|Changed Before? false
14:05:50:686 USER_DEBUG [13]|DEBUG|New Close Date After: 2019-07-01 00:00:00
14:05:50:687 USER_DEBUG [14]|DEBUG|Changed After? true
```

So, you'll need to call you trigger method from the `after update` context, and add DML to commit the reversion to the database:

```
public static void persistOriginalCloseDate(Map<Id, Opportunity> opps, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldOpps) {
    Id maintenanceRecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' AND DeveloperName = 'Maintenance_Renewal'].Id;
    List<Opportunity> oppsForUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
    for (Opportunity opp : opps.values()) {
        Opportunity oldOpp = oldOpps.get(opp.Id);
        if (opp.RecordTypeId == maintenanceRecordTypeId && opp.IsWon == true && oldOpp.IsWon == false && opp.CloseDate != oldOpp.CloseDate) {
            opp.CloseDate = oldOpp.CloseDate;
            oppsForUpdate.add(opp);
            System.debug('persisting');
        } else {
            System.debug('not persisting');
        }
    }
    if (!oppsForUpdate.isEmpty()) {
        update oppsForUpdate;
}
```

A couple other notes:
Your test doesn't set the RecordTypeId of the test Opportunity at first, so it will get the default RT of the test's running user, which is a bad idea, especially when testing functionality that branches on Record Type. You should also break your tests out into separate test methods. Create the Account and Opp in a `@testSetup` method at the top of the class, and then have separate methods for each of your scenarios: allowing system CloseDate change, and reverting it for the one RT. Your `Test.startTest(); Test.stopTest();` pairs should enclose only the DML that saves after updating to Closed/Won, and your asserts should be after.

Comment: So this answer doesn't actually solve the issue I am getting. My trigger method works fine. Salesforce's `__sfdc_trigger/OpportunityTrigger` trigger updates the record which then re-calls my before trigger method and reverts the close date. Sure, my before trigger will be called twice, but that's fine. My issue is getting the updated close date from the salesforce trigger which happens after the transaction is committed (after the test finishes). This solution doesn't solve that issue. The only real solution is to put half of this logic into my `@testSetup method`.

Comment: I recant that putting the update logic in `@testSetup` works. It doesn't seem possible to get the modified close date in a test when salesforce overwrites it.

Comment: I'm not sure what `Salesforce's __sfdc_trigger/OpportunityTrigger` is - there's no default trigger on the Opportunity object by default. And if you "verified there are no other triggers/workflows affecting this process.", I don't see how your trigger method can be working by getting fired twice. Perhaps that trigger is from a Salesforce managed package? The last paragraph of my answer is accurate, though - you need two separate test methods, with the Opp manipulation outside of the `start/stopTest`s and the asserts after. Edit your question with your revised tests and we can take a look.

Comment: If there is no hidden salesforce trigger on opportunity, how else would Salesforce be able to change the close date? This is standard functionality.

Comment: Ah, I see where we're crossing wires - I think using the term "trigger" for that functionality is imprecise - a `trigger` in SFDC is inherently custom or packaged Apex code. Your reference to `__sfdc_trigger/OpportunityTrigger` made me think it was something you could see in your metadata.

Comment: The `__sfdc_trigger/OpportunityTrigger` is something I am seeing in my debug logs. I am assuming this is a hidden trigger that salesforce uses for this use case

Comment: What's the name of the trigger that you're calling `persistOriginalCloseDate(Trigger.newMap,Trigger.oldMap)` from? When you go to Opportunity in Setup and look at Triggers, who's listed as the creator/last editor of OpportunityTrigger? There's no logging of any kind of that system field update when running in a clean scratch org  with logging levels all the way up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95599/discussion-between-programmatic-and-thomas-taylor).